# Best practice to automate SVN checkout as a pre-build event with MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, svn, msbuild

I have a C#/ASP.NET MVC project on Visual Studio 2013

What is the best way to automate an SVN checkout as a pre-build event with MSBuild. I have two options working but I dont know what is considered best practive.

First way was in the csproj file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec ContinueOnError="false" Command="svn co --username my_username --password my_password https://my.repository $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\my\subdirectory" />
</Target>
```

The second was right-click project -> properties -> build events -> pre-build event command line:

`svn co --username my_username --password my_password https://my.repository $(ProjectDir)\my\subdirectory`

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to the first one.

The prebuild command takes the text added to the corresponding field in the project property pane resolving it to this markup:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>svn co --username my_username --password my_password https://my.repository $(ProjectDir)\Clients\LostGarden</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The @(PreBuildEvent) itemgroup would then be handled in Microsoft.Common.Targets:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEventDependsOn></PreBuildEventDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target
      Name="PreBuildEvent"
      Condition="'$(PreBuildEvent)'!=''"
      DependsOnTargets="$(PreBuildEventDependsOn)">

    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PreBuildEvent)" />

  </Target>
```

Next steps would be for you to define inputs and outputs for your BeforeBuild target allowing it to build incrementally so the SVN call :)